# CMMotionManager and the Angular Path

Tags: ios, camera, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion

I'm trying to code a very basic panorama app.

By using CMMotionManager I get motion updates to determine the appropriate moment to take the next picture. Sometimes this code works perfectly well, but in most cases it takes a photo too early or too late. Please help me understand what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Here is an example of code for an iPhone in its portrait mode.

```
#define CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) * 57.29577951f) // PI * 180
#define FOV_IN_PORTRAIT_MODE 41.5;

double prevTime;
double currAngle;

- (void)motionUpdate:(CMDeviceMotion *)motion
{
    if (!prevTime) {
        prevTime = motion.timestamp;
        return;
    }

    //Calculate delta time between previous motionUpdate call and _now_
    double deltaTime = motion.timestamp - prevTime;
    prevTime = motion.timestamp;

    //Y axis rotation
    CMRotationRate rotationRate = motion.rotationRate;
    double rotation = rotationRate.y;

    if (fabs(rotation) < 0.05) //igonre bias
        return;

    //Calculate the angular distance
    double anglePathRad = rotation * deltaTime;

    //calculate total panoram angle
    currAngle += CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(anglePathRad);

    if (fabs(currAngle) >= FOV_IN_PORTRAIT_MODE) {
        currAngle = 0;
        [self takePicture];
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe Bézier curves are the right solution for my problem?

Comment: were you able to solve it ? If yes, please put some light on this issue...